# Tying all values along the diagonal of a matrix in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

The model I am implementing has a set of parameters a1, ..., aH that correspond to weighing previous outputs. It's realized through multiplying a matrix that looks like this:

```
a1  0  0  0  0 ...
a2 a1  0  0  0 ...
a3 a2 a1  0  0 ...
 :  :  :  :  :
```

In the current implementation, the a's are saved in a one-dimensional `nn.parameter.Parameter` with H entries, from which the matrix is constructed during each forward pass. The gradient of the matrix automatically propagates to the parameters via autograd.

However, this requires constructing the matrix anew every forward pass. Is there a way to have the matrix itself be the parameter but tie the weights along the main diagonal and lower subdiagonals so that it is equivalent to constructing it from the parameter vector?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dia_matrix` from [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.dia_matrix)

```
from scipy.sparse import dia_matrix

a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5]

m = dia_matrix([a, b], [0, -1])
print(m)
#   (0, 0)  [1, 2, 3]
#   (0, 1)  [4, 5]
a[0] = 10

print(m)
#   (0, 0)  [10, 2, 3]
#   (0, 1)  [4, 5]
```